# MVC3 & html form. how to get params from URL?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I haven't done web applications before, but I'm familiar with C#, and am trying to create a website using MVC3. 
I have a page with an HTML form, i have it set to use GET method, and on submit to go to a new page.
The new page will load fine, and have the parameters in the URL like this:

```
http://localhost:55751/Home/ClassAdded?Semester_Fall=Summer&Ticket=123&Year=2012
```

On this new page, how do I get the parameters from the URL to work with them in C#? Essentially, I want to just take those params and put them in in a database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at http://www.asp.net/mvc/pluralsight for a nice little introduction.

Easiest way would be to define your model and have a strongly typed view that will send an instance of the model to the controller. There you would (very easily) just store the model instance received to the database (use Entity Framework or a Linq Data Context for that, up to date people would use EF though).

There is no real magic, just get to know the MVC pattern and then how it is implemented in MVC 3 ...

ps: i don't think the question would earn a -1, sure (s)he could have had a go on google... but well *shrug*

Answer (score 2):

I recomend you to read some book: [http://www.amazon.com/Pro-ASP-NET-Framework-Steven-Sanderson/dp/1430210079](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430210079). You need to use action parameters.